Is the Galois conjugate of a Siegel eigenform another eigenform?
Let $F$ be a Siegel cusp form of weight $k\geq2$ (integer), degree two for the group $\text{Sp}_4(\mathbb{Z})$. Suppose it is an eigenform for all the Hecke operators $T(n)$. Let $\sigma$ be an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $F^{\sigma}$ denote the formal series obtained by letting $\sigma$ act on the coefficients of $F$: i.e., if
$$ F(Z) = \sum_{T}A_F(T)e^{2\pi i Tr(TZ)} $$ where $T$ runs over $2\times2$ symmetric, positive definite half-integral matrices, then
$$ F^{\sigma}(Z) : = \sum_{T}\sigma(A_F(T))e^{2\pi i Tr(TZ)}. $$
Question(s): Is $F^{\sigma}$ again an eigenform of degree two for the group $\text{Sp}_4(\mathbb{Z})$? If so, is there an easy proof?
My question is motivated from this question regarding modular forms (of degree one), which asks if $f$ is an eigenform for $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, then is $f^{\sigma}$ also an eigenform (which is true in this case).
Edit: Instead of letting $\sigma$ act on the coefficients $A_F(T)$, what will happen if we consider the new 'formal' series obtained by letting $\sigma$ act on the eigenvalues? I am not sure if this makes sense or not, will this be a Siegel form at least?

@user297024 Can you please elaborate? If there is no easy proof for the first question, can you point out to some references for the same, or give some brief idea of the proof? Also, any idea what will happen to the eigenvalues here?
